# AWS Lambda - SQS Integration with Exponential Backoff

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS Lambda (python) that is triggered by SQS events. If the lambda fails , SQS retries based on the retry settings. How can I make changes to the retry settings to enable exponential backoff?

Comment: The sdk allows you now to specify delay when you put a message in a queue. I am not providing an answer since I have not tried it yet but the way it should work is make sure lambda succeeds but before that put the message back in queue with delay and an extra attribute called e.g. retries so that you can compute the future delay based on this attribute.

Comment: I just found this which describes what I explained but decouples the exponential backoff strategy from your application logic https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-sqs-dead-letter-queues-to-replay-messages/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure you can use an Exponential Backoff if you are using the SQS Trigger because, behind the scenes, this is not essentially a trigger. Lambda keeps polling the SQS queue for messages instead.

SQS will make the message invisible for whatever period is defined in the `Visibility Timeout` attribute, meaning every time a Lambda function picks up a new message, this timeout will be respected before the message is visible by other consumers again.

This leaves you with two options:

1) Don't use the Lambda trigger and poll the queue yourself. Keep in mind that you will also have to manually delete the messages if that's the case.

2) Increase the Visibility Timeout on your source SQS Queue in such a way that the timeout is enough for potential failing systems to recover.

More information on how Lambda processes events from AWS Services can be found in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html)

Comment: Thanks Thales Minussi , this helps. I was thinking of an approach where I could still use the SQS trigger and handle exponential backoff in the code. I could set maximum retries  to say 15. I will continue performing the process when SQS retry count = 1. Then will process retry count = 3 , retry count =7 and retry count = 15. Do you think this approach has any drawback?

Comment: That sounds OK. Except of the fact that your Lambda functions will be triggered in vain many times, unnecessarily increasing costs, but it could work indeed

Comment: Thanks for reviewing @Thales. Yes , I agree , that it will result in unnecessary invocations. However wouldn't I have to implement something similar for option 1? I guess I may have to have cloudwatch alarm to trigger lambda which polls the queue.

Comment: Interesting question, but not necessarily. On scenario 1), you are in control, meaning you can change the visibility timeout in the message level, so you could use this in your favour to figure out your exponential backoff. If you really want to have it implemented, I think the only way is to poll the queue yourself. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks @ThalesMinussi. I still am confused about one part - are you suggesting to have the polling logic in an EC2 instance or lambda ? If it has to be implemented in Lambda , I believe it has to be invoked by cloud watch trigger or something similar to poll the queue.

Comment: I see. IIRC CW triggers need to respect a CRON job, which means it can run every minute, but not more frequent than that since CRON doesn't support scheduled jobs in seconds. Maybe polling every minute is not an option for you. If it is, then Lambda should be just fine to poll your SQS queue. Otherwise EC2 is the way to go